# Is it possible to access files inside an excel spreadsheet with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several files inserted inside it (using the "insert objects" function in Office).

I need to be able to list those files and copy them to a folder in PHP.
Is it possible to do this with PHPExcel ? I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Or is it possible with an other PHP library ?

Comment: No and No.... It should be possible with COM or PUNO, or possibly using the commercial libXl library

Comment: that's what I was afraid of :) Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. 
See Mark Baker comment above.